# Mind Your Idioms!

Tags: rebus, emoji

Emoji Puzzle:

Mind your idioms!

[image]

Text version:

1. ❌
2. ⚫
3. ⏰
4. 
5. 
6. 
7. ✅ ☔
8. ☀️
9. ❌
10. ⏰
11. 
12. 
13. 
14. 
15. ‍♂️
16. 
17. 
18. ☁️
19. 
20. 
21. ☔ ☀️
22. ❌
23. 
24. 
25. 
26. ⚽
27. 
28. 
29. ☀️
30. 
31. 
32. 
33. ⚰️
34. 
35. ☝️
36. 
37. 
38. ☕
39. 
40. 
41. 

Comment: The text version of 1 has an extra `u`, and you should edit your answer to check the 'community wiki' checkbox.

Comment: Hi @Glorfindel.. how are you? Where is that damn checkbox again (  Another Q, can we setup answers to be individually 'markable' as correct/incorrect?

Comment: Hi there! You can [edit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/97434/edit) the answer, then the checkbox becomes visible at the bottom right (IIRC).

Comment: As for the answer, I'd recommend using strikethrough (`<s>test</s>`, it does work in posts) to mark incorrect answers. They'll get overwritten eventually, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

Please answer using the following format:

1 (found by LannyStrack)

> not be caught dead

2 (found by LannyStrack)

> on the spot

3 (found by Glorfindel)

> Around the clock

4 (found by JMP)

> Hit the road

5 (found by @Stiv)

> Safe as houses

6 (found by Stratos)

> Sharp Note

7 (found by JMP)

> Right as rain

8 (found by JMP)

> Soak up the sun

9 (found by @Stiv)

> (He's) no spring chicken

10 (found by LannyStrack)

> <strike>Whale alert</strike> a whale of a time

11 (found by Lakshay Sura)

> <strike>Smoke up</strike> Go up in the smoke.

12 (found by Stratos)

> Going bananas

13 (found by @Stiv)

> (An) old flame

14 (found by Glorfindel)

> What goes around, comes around

15 (found by @Stiv)

> Egg on your face

16 (found by @Stiv)

> Tough cookie

17 (found by Stratos)

> <s>with both eyes open</s> Eye for an eye

18 (found by Lakshay Sura)

> Beyond the clouds

19 (found by @Stiv)

> In hot water

20 (found by @Stiv)

> Wet behind the ears

21 (found by LannyStrack)

> <s>After rain comes sunshine</s> rain or shine

22 (found by Glorfindel)

> It's not rocket science

23 (found by @Stiv)

> Think outside the box

24 (found by JMP)

> Costs an arm and a leg

25 (found by @Stiv)

> The world is your oyster

26 (found by @Stiv)

> On the ball

27 (found by Glorfindel)

> When there's smoke, there's fire

28 (found by )

> <s>curry favor</s>

29 (found by Toby Mak)

> Sunset years

30 (found by @Stiv)

> When the chips are down

31 (found by LannyStrack)

> fire and ice

32 (found by @Stiv)

> Let the cat out of the bag

33 (found by JMP)

> One foot in the grave

34 (found by @Stiv)

> Cat got your tongue

35 (found by JMP)

> One for the road

36 (found by Glorfindel)

> A babe magnet

37 (found by @Stiv)

> A picture's worth a thousand words

38 (found by @Stiv)

> For all the tea in China

39 (found by @Stiv)

> (A) bad egg

40 (found by @Stiv)

> A bite of the cherry

41 (found by @Stiv)

> Catnap

Comment: A this point, all the question marked are incorrect

Comment: sorry, all answers marked with '?' are incorrect.. except (2)

Comment: why has the other answer already been accepted?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong @LannyStrack, but I don't think that it is appropriate for a user to use strikethrough to other people's answers in order to post his/her answer (even if it turns out that it is the correct one). I think that this is OP's responsibility.

Comment: @Stratos - I don't know the protocol. Feel free to mark it up in whatever way you like.